# Plugins not Compiling on iOS - working on Android

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use some Flutter packages - specificially the "[share](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/share)" (send app content to other apps) and "[url_launcher](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher)" (link to web site outside the app). [and I don't think my problem is a bug in either package as they work for others, and they exhibit the same root issue in my build issue]

Setting these up and working on Android emulator and device works fine - both run and work "as advertised".

But when I try to get the iOS side working, I am having issues.  When I go to build/launch, I get a message like this ...

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone X in debug mode...
Skipping compilation. Fingerprint match.
Xcode build done.
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
=== BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
/Users/bruce/repos/ex_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:6:9: fatal error: 'share/SharePlugin.h' file not found
#import <share/SharePlugin.h>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone X.
Exited (sigterm)
```

... and when I open the app in XCode I see the same issues ...

[image]

... the code files being asked for do not exist in the project ...

[image]

... if I remove these packages and run without them, the build runs fine on iOS from 'flutter run' and XCode.

It looks like I am missing a base path if this code gets loaded somewhere else? Or "pub" is not loading the files where they are supposed to go in the project?

Any thoughts on next steps for debugging this?

Comment: So, I did a "flutter create" on a fresh application, and I am able to get these plugins working.  If I can't debug this soon, I will probably create a fresh base project and migrate the code over.

I think this may be a result of a recent "flutter update" (updated versions of flutter (0.2.8 -> 0.3.1) or mismatched versions of "cocoapods" (1.4 vs. 1.5) on different machines.

I'd like to figure out what happened as I forsee future upgrades of flutter and other tools in the ecosystem, and I don't want to recreate the base project every time.

Answer (score 0):

My, lazy, solution to this issue was to create a fresh Flutter app and migrate my custom code over.  If this happens again I will spend more time looking at "diffs" to see what might have changed between solutions.

There were different versions of Flutter involved and different versions of Cocoapods, and one of these mid-development updates could have caused the issue.

I did save the "flutter create" command I used (including the "org" development environments (which is important with iOS especially) development environments (went with Swift and Java) description and name).

I also made the main.dart file a simple ...

```
void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

... so that I can easily wire-up the full app with a few references.

I am trying to track any manual updates to the iOS/Android apps (e.g. icons, Podfiles, Firebase references, etc.) so that this will be also easy to update if necessary.